# creating vbscript to change defualt wallpaper on win7home machines

Tags: vbscript, windows-7, registry, settings, desktop

Need help making this script true. i beleave the first part is done file, but registry needs to be reflected from information 4-8 thank you.

1 'this vbscript should be named DefualtWallpaper.vbs

2 'copy this file to a folder.

3 'cat.jpg image should be in same folder as vbscript.

```
dim filesys
set filesys=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If filesys.FileExists("%cd%\cat.jpg%") Then
filesys.CopyFile "%cd%\cat.jpg%","%windir%\web\wallpaper\windows"
```

4.'change registry to new file

```
Set WShellObj=createobject("WScriptShell")
WShellObject.RegWrite "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\DesktopBackground","%WINDIR%\WINDOWS\Web\Wallpaper\Windows\cat.bmp","REG_EXPAND_SZ"
Set WShellObj=nothing
```

5. i get a error at line 18 char 54 error expected 'end' code 800A03f6 from microsft VBScript combilation error. on a win 7 home 64bit,
6. Key name: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes`
7. keytype: `REG_EXPAND_SZ`
8. key: `DesktopBackground`
9. Data: `%WINDIR%\WINDOWS\Web\Wallpaper\Windows\cat.bmp`

Comment: the error you have because of  no *End If* .then you can't change in registry most of key without Run as Administrator or just copy in critical file in windows directory.and there is  other error in typing correct names or code .

Answer (score 2):

Try this one from spicework forum:

```
reg.exe load HKU\DefUser "C:\Documents and Settings\Default User\ntuser.dat"
reg.exe add "HKU\DefUser\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /d "c:\windows\wallpaper\desktop.bmp" /f
reg.exe unload HKU\DefUser
```

The link is here:
http://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/327-batch-file-to-set-the-default-wallpaper

Answer (score 1):

This VBScript for:

1-Run script as administrator
2-Copy my image to the directory where the background image saved
3-Change the current desk background image to my image From registry
4-Force Log off the current user to apply the change

```
'run the script as Administrator
If WScript.Arguments.Length=0 Then
CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "wscript.exe",Chr(34)&WScript.ScriptFullName&Chr(34)&" Admin",Null,"runas",1
WScript.Quit 
End If 
'copy the image from to
Dim WShellObj : Set WShellObj=createobject("WScript.Shell")
Dim filesys   : set filesys=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If filesys.FileExists(WShellObj.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%cd%")&"\cat.jpg") Then
WShellObj.Run "cmd.exe /c copy ""%cd%\cat.jpg""  %windir%\web\wallpaper\windows",0,False
End If 
'change desktop wallpaper through registry
WShellObj.RegWrite  "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\Wallpaper","%WINDIR%\Web\Wallpaper\Windows\cat.jpg","REG_SZ"

'force log off to apply the change of wallpaper
Dim oSystem
For Each oSystem In  GetObject ("winmgmts:{(Shutdown)}//./root/cimv2").ExecQuery("select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")
  oSystem.Win32Shutdown 4
Next
```